# Can Ruby matrixes be passed directly to R with rinruby?

Tags: ruby, r

The rinruby paper only shows very simple datatypes being sent to R. Does this mean that if I want to use a Ruby matrix in R I've got to pass it to R vector for vector and glue them together into a matrix in R?

Comment: How did you solve this vector by vector?

Comment: Dunno, using pandas for the last year. Can't remember squat except ruby being great for many things, but stats isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that they cannot.

Based on http://www.jstatsoft.org/v29/i04/paper, only simple scalars and one-dimensional arrays can be assigned to R from Ruby.

I tried an array of arrays anyway and got this result:

```
RuntimeError: Unsupported data type on Ruby's end
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:656:in `rescue in assign_engine'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:635:in `assign_engine'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:405:in `assign'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rinruby-2.0.3/lib/rinruby.rb:359:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Sorry for the seemingly lazy question, btw. I was planning a new project without a computer available.